# Предусмотрена ли в CoordinatorLayout возможность выставить один элемент относительно другого?

Tags: android, xml, material-design, coordinator-layout

Создана активити с разметкой CoordinatorLayout. В ней присутствуют toolbar  и include, в который помещается контейнер для фрагмента. Вот код активити:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_fragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.labtmp.DetailDeviceActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_activity_fragment"
        />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

мой инклуд автоматически привязывает верх к parent, т.е. к CoordinatorLayout. Toolbar Закрывает часть моего ListFragment. Неужели в данном виде разметки нет возможности прикрепить верх Include к низу toolbar? В примерах MaterialDesign в интернете поле контента ползает за границей toollbar в зависимости от прокрутки... Значит, это возможно.
**UPD.** Я попробовал програмно создать подстраиваемый marginy, но у меня не получилось:

```
private ViewGroup setNeededHeightOfInclude (ViewGroup container){
        container.setTop(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolBarContainer).getHeight());
        return container;
    }
```

Вызовом данного метода пытался изменить ViewGroup, передаваемую в метод onCreateView фрагмента.

Comment: CoordinatorLayout основан на FrameLayout, возможности позиционирования у него аналогичные. Из доступных вариантов - указать фрагменту маржин равный высоте тулбара

Comment: да, но в туториалах по материал дизайну часто встречается лист вью, который не закрывается тулбаром, причем без применения маржина. Я не могу понять, почему у них так, а у меня нет.

Answer (score 1):

Для `viewGroup`, который находится после `AppBarLayout`, можно выставить: `app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"` 
Надеюсь, это кому-нибудь поможет :)